# switch on java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I just trid this code but the result is no different
on biaya.setText anyone can help?

```
String perintah="select jenis_parkir from parkir ";
rss=stm.executeQuery(perintah);
rss.next();
String tipepark=rss.getString("jenis_parkir");
switch (tipepark) {
    case "Non Member":
       biaya.setText(""+vbiaya);
       break;
    case "Member":
       biaya.setText("0");
       break;
}
```

sorry if my english is terrible :

Comment: Is either case of your case statements executing? Add a `default` case with a print statement to make sure the values you are expecting are actually what you are getting. Or better yet leverage the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your project has to declare source level 1.7 or higher. Older versions of Java do not support this language feature.

Comment: but i wear the latest version of netbeans i have version 7.4 on my system, any other option? maybe

Comment: Open Project Tab (Ctrl-1), select your project, open its customizer using  `Properties` item in its context menu, `Sources` tab, Source/Binary Format needs to be JDK 7 or higher.
BTW: Latest NetBeans version at the moment is 8.0. Also NetBeans version, Java version, and Java source level used by compiler are different things.